# 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u' in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u` error on my login page. I am working with angularjs and localstorage.

HTML

```
<div class="login-body">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-4">
         <form class="form-horizontal" name="LoginForm">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="ejinputtext input-field col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" ng-model="user.username" name="UserName" placeholder="Username" style="margin-bottom: 15px; margin-top: 30px;" required/>
               </div>
               <span class="error" ng-show="$root.submitted && Loginform.UserName.$error.required">Enter Username!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <input type="password" class="ejinputtext input-field col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" name="Password" required />
               </div>
               <span class="error" ng-show="$root.submitted && Loginform.Password.$error.required">Enter Password!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
               <label style="padding-left:0px">
               <input type="checkbox" ej-checkbox e-size= "small" >
               Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group text-center">
               <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <button  ej-button  e-size= "large" ng-click="login(user)">Log in</button>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
               <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <a href="ForgetPassword.html">Request new password</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('HRApp.controllers', ['ngStorage']);
app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $localStorage, $location) {

    $scope.user = {
        username: "",
        password: "",


    };

    var list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    if (list != undefined && list != '') {
        $scope.user = list;
    }

    $scope.login = function (user) {

        $scope.user.username = user.username;
        $scope.user.password = user.password;

        localStorage.setItem('Login Details', JSON.stringify($scope.user));

        var path = "layout.html";
        location.replace(path);

    };


});
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you need to `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')`? And `localStorage` should be `$localStorage`, same with `location` -> `$location`

Comment: What library is `ngStorage`

Comment: The exception usually occurs when undefined is passed to JSON.parse

Answer (score 1):

That error is normally seen when the value given to `JSON.parse` is actually `undefined`.

So before calling `JSON.parse` on `localStorage.getItem("user")` check for its truthy value.

```
var list = $localStorage.getItem('user') ? JSON.parse($localStorage.getItem('user')) : undefined;
```

Some suggestions:

In your `HTML` you have used `ng-model` for the `input` fields.

So you need not pass `user` object to the `login` method. By default, the values will be set in `$scope.user.username` and `$scope.user.password`.

so your `login` method will become:

```
$scope.login = function (user) {
        $localStorage.setItem('Login Details', JSON.stringify($scope.user)); 
        // make sure it should be Login Details / user
        var path = "layout.html";
        $location.replace(path);
    };
```

The problem is with `localStorage.getItem("user")`. I don't see anywhere you are setting `localStorage.setItem("user")`. Even in the login method you have `localStorage.setItem("Login Details")`.

Comment: check for JSON.parse($localStorage.getItem('user'))

Comment: check console and see in which line the error is coming.

Comment: When you click the line in console, it will take you the js code. What code do you see there

Comment: could you setup jsfiddle/jsbin for me to check?>

Answer (score 0):

You use a variable `localStorage` instead of `$localStorage`. Fix this, and tell us if you sill have your error.

Same problem with `location` var (it must be `$location`).

Comment: You have access to localStorage as it's global

Comment: OK, but he tries to use an Angular provider `$localStorage` prodived by an AngularJS plugin, not the global localStorage.

Comment: $localStorage is again a wrapper around localStorage

Comment: @mohamedrias: I assume (I don't know the ngStorage plugin) this wrapper exists to provide angular data-binding mecanism to `localStorage`.

Comment: @Tejaswini: why do you include an Angular plugin which manages localStorage if you only want to use the default `localStorage` ? If you want it, as @mohamedrias tells, it's a global variable so you can directly use `localStorage` in your code.

Comment: @Tejaswini if you want to make a global variable part of Angular, you can do `angular.module('someModule', []).value('localStorage', localStorage)` this allows you to then inject it