# SyntaxError: Unexpected token u Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```js
//Define angular app
var app = angular.module('ToDoApp', []);

//controllers
app.controller('taskController', function($scope) {
  $scope.today = new Date();
  $scope.saved = localStorage.getItem('taskItems');
  $scope.taskItem = (localStorage.getItem('taskItems') !== null) ?
    JSON.parse($scope.saved) : [{
      description: "Why not add a task?",
      date: $scope.today,
      complete: false
    }];
  localStorage.setItem('taskItems', JSON.stringify($scope.taskItem));

  $scope.newTask = null;
  $scope.newTaskDate = null;
  $scope.categories = [{
    name: 'Personal'
  }, {
    name: 'Work'
  }, {
    name: 'School'
  }, {
    name: 'Cleaning'
  }, {
    name: 'Other'
  }];
  $scope.newTaskCategory = $scope.categories;
  $scope.addNew = function() {
    if ($scope.newTaskDate == null || $scope.newTaskDate == '') {
      $scope.taskItem.push({
        description: $scope.newTask,
        date: "No deadline",
        complete: false,
        category: $scope.newTaskCategory.name
      })
    } else {
      $scope.taskItem.push({
        description: $scope.newTask,
        date: $scope.newTaskDate,
        complete: false,
        category: $scope.newTaskCategory.name
      })
    };
    $scope.newTask = '';
    $scope.newTaskDate = '';
    $scope.newTaskCategory = $scope.categories;
    localStorage.setItem('taskItems', JSON.stringify($scope.taskItem));
  };
  $scope.deleteTask = function() {
    var completedTask = $scope.taskItem;
    $scope.taskItem = [];
    angular.forEach(completedTask, function(taskItem) {
      if (!taskItem.complete) {
        $scope.taskItem.push(taskItem);
      }
    });
    localStorage.setItem('taskItems', JSON.stringify($scope.taskItem));
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('taskItems', JSON.stringify($scope.taskItem));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ToDoApp">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content" ng-controller="taskController">
      <h1>Welcome to your to do List</h1>
      <p class="tagline">By <a href="http://www.flintdesignz.co.za" target="_blank">Flintdesignz</a>
      </p>

      <form>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="inputContainer">
            <input type="text" id="description" class="taskName" placeholder="I need to..." ng-model="newTask">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="inputContainer"> <i class="fa fa-caret-down selectArrow"></i>
            <select id="category" class="taskCategory" ng-model="newTaskCategory" ng-options="obj.name for obj in categories">
              <option class="disabled" value="">Category</option>
            </select>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="inputContainer">
            <input type="date" id="dueDate" class="taskDate" ng-model="newTaskDate">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row buttons_holder">
          <button class="taskAdd" ng-click="addNew()"><i class="fa fa-plus icon"></i>Add task</button>
          <button class="taskDelete" ng-click="deleteTask()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o icon"></i>Remove Tasks</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- TaskList Starts Here -->
      <ul class="taskList">
        <li class="taskItem" ng-repeat="taskItem in taskItem track by $index" ng-model="taskItem">
          <input type="checkbox" class="taskCheckbox" ng-model="taskItem.complete" ng-change="save()">
          <span class="complete-{{taskItem.complete}}">{{taskItem.description}}</span>  <span class="category-{{taskItem.category}}">{{taskItem.category}}</span>  <strong class="taskDate complete-{{taskItem.complete}}"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>{{taskItem.date | date : 'mediumDate'}}</strong> 
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- TaskList Ends HEre -->
    </div>
    <!-- Content Ends Here -->
  </div>
  <!-- container -->
</div>
```

Building a Todo App that adds tasks and deletes them aswell and getting the above error. Below is my html and my angular code. I have checked other blogs and still no valid answer.

Comment: Take a look a [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850861/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-in-angularjs).

Comment: I tried that method but had no luck.changed 'localStorage' to '$localStorage' and still the same error